# How send invoices via API in ActiveCollab?

Tags: activecollab

How send invoices via API in ActiveCollab?

I don't see anything about it in API Docs: https://developers.activecollab.com/api-documentation/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Necessary information can be found on the Invoices page:
https://developers.activecollab.com/api-documentation/v1/invoicing/invoices/invoices.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).